# SQL Server does not throw exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In last statement of query, I reference a column that does not exists in `Table2` and SQL Server does not validate that error and after execution, I got all columns that are exists in `Table1` without any rows.

I think that this is wrong because return value give us information that `WHERE` query did not find any rows instead of throwing a mistake.

Can you explain why SQL Server have that behavior?

Written in SQL Server 2014, SSMS 2016.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.Table1; 

CREATE TABLE Table1 
( 
    ID INT, 
    FirstName VARCHAR(50) 
)

INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, FirstName) 
VALUES 
    (1, 'Bob'), 
    (2, 'Peter'), 
    (3, 'Joe');

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table2', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.Table2; 

CREATE TABLE Table2 
( 
    ID INT, 
    SecondName VARCHAR(50) 
)

INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, SecondName) 
VALUES 
    (1, 'Meggy'), 
    (2, 'Paula'), 
    (3, 'Stella');

SELECT * 
FROM 
    Table1 
WHERE 
    FirstName NOT IN (SELECT FirstName FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The columns from the outer query are visible in the inner query. So in fact, for each row in table1, you selected that row's `FirstName` as a constant value from table2, returning the same value for each row of table2. Since a value obviously exists in the list of itself multiple times, no rows were returned.

One way to avoid such mistakes is to fully qualify the columns you query. If you do that, you'd get the error you expect:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Table1 t1
WHERE 
    t1.FirstName NOT IN 
    ( 
    -- Produces an error, since there's no FirstName in Table2
    SELECT t2.FirstName FROM Table2 t2 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for you Answer, but, I know what aliases do and how avoid that mistake.
I wrote this question because this is, for me, not good implementation in SQL Server.

For me this is nearer to throw Exception than return information that have empty rows.